# Quandl returning only empty data frames for requests from 3/27/2018 to now

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I'm using Quandl to get daily stock prices, but trying to get any data after the date 3/27/18 returns an empty dataframe.

```py
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# add quandl API key for unrestricted
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'MY_API_KEY_HERE'

# get the table for daily stock prices and, filter the table for selected tickers, columns within a time range
data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'WMT'], 
                        qopts = { 'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'adj_close'] }, 
                        date = { 'gte': '2018-3-20', 'lte': dt.datetime.now() }, 
                        paginate=True)

# create a new dataframe with 'date' column as index
new = data.set_index('date')

# use pandas pivot function to sort adj_close by tickers
clean_data = new.pivot(columns='ticker')

print(clean_data)
```

For example, using 2018-3-20 for a date will return expected date through 2018-3-26, but it stops the output there.

See output:

```
          adj_close
ticker          AAPL   MSFT    WMT
date
2018-03-20   175.240  93.13  87.95
2018-03-21   171.270  92.48  88.18
2018-03-22   168.845  89.79  87.14
2018-03-23   164.940  87.18  85.42
2018-03-26   172.770  93.78  87.50
```

Trying to make the starting date 2018-3-27 (or anything after that) outputs this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Does Quandl not support this data? Do I need to pay for something to get it? Or am I doing something wrong on my end?

Comment: Can you query the data using a webpage?

Comment: Just got done trying that, looks like the dataset was discontinued right around the last date that's available. I guess I'll have to find another way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

The dataset was discontinued in March 2018.  https://help.quandl.com/article/398-why-does-wiki-prices-only-go-up-to-march-2018